# Magic: the Gathering - Standard Speed

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Playing with a Standard-legal Magic: The Gathering deck, your goal is to win a game as quickly as possible, against an opponent who does nothing. You may assume that your deck is stacked, so that you will always draw exactly the cards you want.

You may choose to play or draw, but winning turn 4 on the play is considered faster than winning turn 4 on the draw. In the event that two solutions tie for speed, the winner will be the solution that deals more damage.

**Possibly Asked Questions:**
At the time of asking, Standard-legal Magic cards are any cards printed in Khans of Tarkir, Fate Reforged, Dragons of Tarkir, Magic Origins, or Battle for Zendikar.
If you care about the opponent at all, assume their deck consists of sixty islands and they begin the game with a mulligan to zero.
I know it's possible to deal approximately 35 damage turn 3 on the play, so if you're not there yet you definitely haven't found the optimal solution.

Comment: It's possible to deal 35 on what turn? Also, what's with the unused link to Zo-Zu the Punisher in your text? :P

Comment: Fixed and fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"Looks like you can't go infinite before turn four, so this is probably just won by the most aggressive strategy"* - a quote from myself.  I was wrong.  You can totally go infinite on turn 3 on the play.

**Turn 3 on the Play, Main Phase 1: Infinite Damage**

> **Turn 1:** [Yavimaya Coast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398566), [Honored Hierarch](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398450) (5 cards)
>
>  **Turn 2:** [Wooded Foothills](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405116) > Mountain, [Atarka’s Command](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394502), dealing 3 and putting a [Windswept Heath](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405115) into play (3 cards, 2 gy)
>
>  Windswept Heath > Plains, [Defiant Strike](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386515) on Hierarch, draw 1, attack with Hierarch becoming renowned (3 cards, 4 gy)
>
>  **Turn 3:** [Polluted Delta](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405104) > Island (3 cards, 5 gy)
>
>  Tap Island, Plains, Mountain for [Jeskai Ascendancy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386571) (2 cards, 5 gy)
>
>  Tap HH for R, play [Magmatic Insight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398496), discarding Swamp, draw two, untap HH, loot a card (2 cards, 8 gy)
>
>  Tap HH for U, play [Treasure Cruise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386705) delving 7, untap HH, loot a card (4 cards, 3 gy)
>
>  Tap HH for R, play [Magmatic Insight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398496), discarding Swamp, draw two, untap HH, loot a card (4 cards, 6 gy)
>
>  Tap HH for R, play [Spidersilk Net](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394708), untap HH, loot a card (R, 3 cards, 7 gy)
>
>  Tap HH for W, tap Yavimiaya Coast for U, play [Jeskai Ascendency](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386571), untap HH, loot a card (2 cards, 8 gy)
>
>  Tap HH for U, play [Treasure Cruise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386705) delving 7, untap/tap HH for UW, loot twice (UW, 4 cards, 4 gy)
>
>  Play [Spidersilk Net](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394708), untap/tap HH for UR, loot twice (UUWR, 3 cards, 6 gy)
>
>  Play [Jeskai Ascendency](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386571), untap/tap HH for WR, loot once (UWR, 2 cards, 7 gy)
>
>  Play [Jeskai Ascendency](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386571), untap/tap HH for UUW (UUW, 1 card, 7 gy)
>
>  Play [Treasure Cruise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386705) delving 7, untap/tap HH for UUUW (UUUUUWW, 3 cards)
>
>  Play [Soulfire Grand Master](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=391927) (UUUW, 2 cards)
>
>  Play [Defiant Strike](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386515) on HH, draw one, untap/tap HH for UUUU (UUUUUUU, 2 cards)
>
>  Play [Disperse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398528) targeting Spidersilk Net for UU, trigger Soulfire Grand Master for UUUU to return Disperse to your hand, untap/tap HH for UUUU (UUUUU, 1 card, Spidersilk Net, Disperse)
>
>  Play [Spidersilk Net](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394708), untap/tap HH for UURR (UUUUUUURR, 1 card, Disperse)
>
>  Repeat the previous two steps an infinite number of times, gaining RR each time until you have infinite R (Infinite R, 1 card, Disperse)
>
>  Play [Rolling Thunder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=402015) for X = infinite, targeting your opponent for all of it, dealing infinite damage and gaining infinite life as well

---

But maybe Jeskai Ascendancy and Treasure Cruise are too easy; after all, both have seen play in Legacy (and even Vintage).  Lets go infinite without using a single non-land card that's seen play outside of Standard.

---

**Turn 3 on the Play, Main Phase 1: Another Infinite Damage Combo**

> Turn 1: Forest, [Obscuring Aether](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394637) (5 cards)
>
>  Turn 2: Forest, [Obscuring Aether](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394637) x2, [Rattleclaw Mystic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386634) x3 face down (0 cards)
>
>  Turn 3: Unmorph Rattleclaw Mystic #1 for GG, add RGU, tap for U.  Play [Secret Plans](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386657) for GU. (RU, 0 cards)
>
>  Unmorph Rattleclaw Mystic #2 for RU, add RGU, draw a card, tap for U (RGUU, 1 card)
>
>  Unmorph Rattleclaw Mystic #3 for RG, add RGU, draw a card, tap for U (RGUUUU, 2 cards)
>
>  Play [Rattleclaw Mystic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386634) #4 face down, unmorph it for RU, add RGU, draw a card (RGGUUUU, 2 cards)
>
>  Play [Temur Ascendancy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386692) for RGU, tap Mystic #4 for R (RGUUU, 1 card)
>
>  Play [Clutch of Currents](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=401844) for U, returning Mystic #1, replay it face down, unmorph Mystic #1 for RG, add RGU, draw a card, tap for U (RGUUUU, 1 card)
>
>  Repeat the previous step three more times (RGUUUUUUU, 1 card)
>
>  Play [Sidisi's Faithful](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394696), exploiting itself for U, returning Mystic #1, replay it face down, unmorph Mystic #1 for RG, add RGU, draw a card, tap for U (RGUUUUUUUU, 1 card)
>
>  Repeat the previous step three more times (RGUUUUUUUUUUU, 1 card)
>
>  Play [Learn from the Past](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394614) for UUUU, targeting yourself, shuffling in everything and drawing a card (RGUUUUUUU, 1 card)
>
>  Repeat the above cycles with Clutch x4, Sidisi's Faithful x4, gaining U per card and drawing one off each (RGUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU, 1 card)
>
>  Play [Learn from the Past](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394614) for UUUU, targeting yourself, shuffling in everything (including the other Learn from the Past) and drawing a card (RGUUUUUUUUUUU, 1 card)
>
>  Repeat the above two steps an infinite number of times, gaining infinite U (RG, infinite U, 1 card)
>
>  Play [Crater's Claws](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386509) for X = infinite, targeting your opponent, dealing them infinite damage

---

Previous Solution

---

39 damage Turn 3 on the play.

> Turn 1: Wooded Foothills, crack it for a Forest, Scythe Leopard. (5 cards, 1 in yard, 0 damage)
>
>  Turn 2: Wooded Foothills, crack it for a Mountain, Atarka's Command dealing 3 and putting Wooded Foothills in play, crack it for Canopy Vista, Defiant Strike on Scythe Leopard. Attack with Scythe Leopard for 6 damage. (3 cards, 5 in yard, 9 damage this turn)
>
>  Turn 3: Wooded Foothills, crack it for a Cinder Glade, Animist's Awakening for X = 3, revealing Windswept Heath x3, crack for Cinder Glade x3, Become Immense on Scythe Leopard, delving 5, Temur Battle Rage on Scythe Leopard, giving double strike. Attack with Scythe Leopard for 15+15 damage. (0 cards, 7 in yard, 30 damage this turn)

Comment: On turn 2 you play 4 cards (Foothills, Command, another Foothills, Leopard) but you seem to have only counted 3. Your solution comes up short one card.

Comment: Replaced with Defiant Strike for now, which is 5 less damage, but definitely works.

Comment: I see a way to optimize a bit more damage of this approach, would you like the tip or should I let you figure it out?

Comment: Give me at least a few minutes - I'm still pondering, since Defiant Strike x2 is definitely an ugly answer.

Comment: ...Okay, what've you got?  I can't find a more efficient pump spell than "+8/+8 for G" which is effectively Animist's Awaking, I can't find a good way to get the second instant/sorcery into the yard without eating up a mana that turn or losing a leopard, and the most I can deal with a single leopard is 28.

Comment: You can get one more damage by finishing with Temur Battle Rage on the 8/7, instead of Become Immense + Defiant Strike. To deal the approximately 35 damage I mentioned, you'll need to try something different, rather than optimizations of this approach.

Comment: Forgot Temur Battle Rage was a card... okay, that takes us back to 35 easily.

Comment: Nicely done, I had missed the play of Defiant Strike turn 2 to set up Awakening for 3. You've got my best solution beat now.

Comment: The only other solutions I could think of that are in this league are going infinite (basically impossible; you'd need at least one of the Ascendancies or an awakened land in play on turn 2, and the only turn 1 ramp card is elves only), goblins with Piledriver (can't get enough in play, and there are no hasty 1 mana goblins), and elves tribal into Atarka's Command (but I can't see you getting more than five elves in play before turn 3, which is far from enough).  So, I'm comfortable claiming this solution is optimal.  (Shaman of Forgotten Ways would also work, but there's no way to ramp that)

Comment: I had a solution for 36 that went T1 Swiftspear, T2 Hangarback for zero, Hangarback for zero, Grave Strength, T3 Become Immense, Battlerage. I'll give it a while to see if anyone finds some draft chaff that somehow leads to 40 damage.

Comment: Alright, I concede that I was wrong.  Solution improved.

Comment: Technically it's not infinite damage and only 20 damage because the game ends when dealt 20 damage. So your first solution is actually better

Comment: Just for you, I'll make it do infinite damage in one shot.

Comment: @Zerris nice one!

Comment: Nicely done, I saw the infinite solution as soon as you mentioned Ascendancy and wondered how long it would take.

Comment: As for the infinite combo, you can just attack with the two infinitely pumped Hierarchs, you don't even need to generate infinite mana, as long as you can keep recasting a spell over and over.

Comment: @orp you can't, you need to attack with the second Hierarch to get renown, or you can't do the combo.

Comment: @DrunkWolf: True, but one of them had attacked the turn before to get renown so you can still attack with that one.

Comment: @orp you only have 1 combat phase..

Comment: Derp, never mind me. Slow morning ><

Comment: My earlier attempt was to go infinite off Ascendancy + Noyan Dar, Roil Shaper, which was why I felt I didn't have enough mana on turn 3. But then I remembered standard has a faux Birds of Paradise that nobody plays, which makes it much easier.

Comment: I do feel that this isn't the quickest way to win, in fact, playing it out takes quite a while, and you need a whole extra phase to finish him off.. I guess infinite damage makes up for It though :) good job, don't see anyone beating this

Comment: I think you can go infinite before combat, but it's *really* nasty, and involves delving away most of your deck.  Also, turn 2 on the draw is so close... but I can't beat 16 damage.  In case anybody wants to try, the obvious lines are Swiftspear x3 > Spidersilk Net x4 (16), Swiftspear x2 > Defiant Strike, Spidersilk Net x5 (16), and Swiftspear > Spidersilk Net x5 > Temur Battle Rage (15).

Comment: There, moved the combo back from main phase 2 to main phase 1; it's now faster than anything using the combat step.

Comment: And added in a second combo that doesn't need Jeskai Ascendancy or Treasure Cruise.

Answer (score 2):

Turn 3 on the play.

**Turn 1:** Forest, Scythe Leopard.
**Turn 2:** Wooded Foothills, crack it for a Mountain, Monastery Swiftspear, Scythe Leopard, attack for 4. 
**Turn 3:** Wooded Foothills, crack it for a Cinder Glade, Monastery Swiftspear, Atarka's Command (3 damage to opponent and +1/+1 to your dudes), triggering prowess, attack with 2 4/4's and 2 3/4's for 14.

**Total:** 21 damage.

Comment: Good job. You could improve it a bit by instead of playing Swiftspear, Commanding in a fetchland and using it to cast a pump spell.

Comment: That's true. If you did that and used Titan's Strength you'd another 9 damage (but lose 4 from not using the pump mode).